# PrintPreview inconsistent behavior

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Sub PrintSheet()

' Print sent to Print Preview so user can check output and send it to
' the desired printer!

    If Range("Committee_Name") <> "" Then
      ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintPreview
    Else
      With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
          .PrintTitleRows = "$14:$16"
          .PrintTitleColumns = ""
          .CenterHeader = _
            "&""Verdana,Regular""&16WPOA: Longe Range Planning Committee Summary"
          .CenterFooter = "Page &P of &N"
          .RightFooter = "as of: &D"
          .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
          .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
          .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
      End With
      'The True argument to PrintPreview allows the Print Dialog to appear.
      'w/o this argument it goes right to the default printer.
      'However, for some reason it is not necessary in the code above!
      Range("Data_Table").PrintPreview (True)
    
    End If
            
End Sub  'PrintSheet
```

In the True branch of the If once the preview is displayed and I click on the Print button I get the print dialog box as expected. However, in the False (Else) branch if I don't include the True parameter for changes it goes directly to my default printer w/o displaying the dialog box. It would appear that the inclusion of the PrintSetup code is causing this but why?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can see is that the behavior of the PrintPreview method is different depending on whether it's invoked on a Sheets object or a Range object.

1. [MSDN article for Sheets.PrintPreview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets.printpreview)
2. [MSDN article for Range.PrintPreview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.printpreview?view=excel-pia)

Based on your experience, it seems like the default behavior when `EnableChanges` is not supplied is True in case 1 (Sheets) and False in case 2 (Range). However, this might be different depending on the version of Excel.